# Is AMS (Schiphol) Polderbaan the runway furthest away?

Tags: airport, taxiing, eham

I'm very interested to learn if there are (m)any (major) (commercial) airports that have runways further away from the terminal(s) than Schiphol's Polderbaan. Which airport is "in the lead" in this respect?

> The northern end of the Polderbaan, the last runway to be constructed, is 7 km (4.3 mi) north of the control tower, causing taxi times of up to 20 minutes to the terminal.
>
> [...]
>
> Newest runway, opened 2003.
> Located to reduce the noise impact on the surrounding population; aircraft have a lengthy 15-minute taxi to and from the Terminal.

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Airport_Schiphol#Runways)</sup>

Comment: Not sure on the distances but KDEN is a candidate.

Comment: @casey Using Google Maps measurement tool, the northern threshold of the Polderbaan is about 6800m (4.25mi) from the tower; the farthest threshold from KDEN's tower is about 4900m (3.1mi).

Comment: I think it's important to emphasise that the there's no space at the end of the Poolderbaan to turn planes, so the maximum distance used on a regular basis will probably be from the first taxiway.

Comment: I've sadly experienced this half-an-hour taxi on about 10 easyJet flights from Liverpool to Amsterdam.

Comment: @Manfred Good point. And that distance is only 5400m (3.4mi).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible contender is Pyongyang airport. The far end of the new runway (01/19) is around 7 km away from the terminal (as the crow flies). With taxi distance, it is almost 8 km:

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.jspacesystems.or.jp/ersdac/ASTERimage3/Image/Asia/INJ_Pyongyang.jpg)</sup>

While the taxi times at Amsterdam can be very long, it is a bit misleading to blame it on the runway being 7 km away. Runway 18R is not used for takeoff. Unlike Pyongyang, there is no parallel taxiway on that 'end' of the runway, and Schiphol ATC would never want to wait for an aircraft to backtrack. Hence, it would be more sensible to use the distance from the first taxiway for landing aircraft on 18R, located 5.5 km from the tower.

Comment: From the Google Maps measurement tool, the end of the northern runway is about 6900m (4.25mi) from the approximate centre of the terminal area, so I think we have a new leader!

Comment: Note that the long taxi times are often due to parallel operations on 18C/36C, in which case airplanes landing from 18R have to take a large detour as crossing 18C/36C is generally not allowed during parallel operations.